# Django Form is not updating the user database

Tags: python, django

I want to update User database using forms.When I trying to update it remains same the database and not update. So to perform this task ?
**forms.py**

```
from django import forms
from django.contrib.auth.models import User
class updateform(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model=User
        fields="__all__"
```

**views.py**

```
from django.contrib.auth.models import User
from .forms import updateform
@permission_required('is_superuser')#only superuser can update the data base
def upform(request,id):
    emp=User.objects.get(id=id)
    if request.method=='POST':
        frm=updateform(request.POST,instance=emp)
        if frm.is_valid():
            frm.save()
            return redirect('/')
    else:
        frm=updateform(instance=emp)
    return render(request,'examp.html',{'frm':frm})
```

**examp.html**

```
{% load static %}
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Title</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="{% static '/examp.css' %}">
    <style>
        td,th{
        border:1px solid;
        text-align:center;
        padding:10px;
        }
    </style>
</head>
<body>
    {% include 'include/header.html' %}
    <form action="/" method="POST">
    {% csrf_token %}
    {{ frm.as_p }}
    <input type="submit" value="Submit">
</form>
</body>
</html>
```

How to update the database using this given form.

Comment: at first look the code look fine but did you check in the admin panel if the data gets updated or not?

Comment: yes, i have checked.

Comment: Are you sure <form action="/" method="POST">, does not need to be only <form method="POST"> ?

Comment: yes, I'm sure. It redirect to the home page after submit.

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you use CBV generic views?

in yourapp/models.py:

```
from django.db import models
from django.urls import reverse
from django.contrib.auth import get_user_model

# const for get_absolute_url
#that's suffix will be using in your template names look at urls.py,
#if you need u should change it for smth here and in urls!
DETAIL_SUFFIX = '_detail'

class YourModel(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(default='new', max_length=6)
    updated_by = models.ForeignKey(get_user_model(), on_delete=models.PROTECT, 
                    related_name='get_upd_by_user')

    def __str__(self):
        return f'{self.name}'
    def get_absolute_url(self):
        return reverse(f'{self.__class__.__name__}{DETAIL_SUFFIX}', kwargs={"pk": self.pk})
```

You need to define the get_absolute_url method. Then reverse will works properly after you update.

in yourapp/views.py:

```
#views
from django.views.generic.edit import UpdateView
from django.views.generic import DetailView
# AAA
from django.contrib.auth.mixins import LoginRequiredMixin
from django.contrib.auth.mixins import PermissionRequiredMixin
    
class ProjectSubnetDetailView(LoginRequiredMixin, DetailView):
    model = YourModel
    template_name = 'your_name_detail.html'  
      
        

class YourNameUpdateView(LoginRequiredMixin, PermissionRequiredMixin, UpdateView):
        model = YourModel
        template_name = 'your_name_edit.html'
        fields = ('somefield', )
        permission_required = ('yourapp.view_yourmodel','yourapp.change_yourmodel')
    
        def form_valid(self, form): # Bind name of current user
            form.instance.updated_by = self.request.user
            return super().form_valid(form)
```

Instead of decorator @permission_required in CBV you can use PermissionRequiredMixin(I highly recommend reading about it in the official documentation). **In short you must define only in this order**:
(LoginRequiredMixin, PermissionRequiredMixin, UpdateView)
First - user must be Authenticated
Second - user must have a rights (or roles, that have a need rights)
Third - thats your generic view for do smth (in this example is update)

For second Attention You must specify in the view those rights that are checked before performing the update in strictly lowercase.

You can define rights in admin panel for some user or create a role and define some rights and add your user into that role. For example i create user and define him some rights for view and change table:
[image]

So if your model is called 'YourModel', you should specify 'action_yourmodel'

```
permission_required = ('yourapp.view_yourmodel','yourapp.change_yourmodel')
```

in yourapp/urls.py.

```
from django.urls import path
from .views import YourNameUpdateViewUpdateView, YourNameDetailView

urlpatterns = [
    path('YourName/<int:pk>/edit/', YourNameUpdateView.as_view(), name='some_name_edit'),
    path('YourName/<int:pk>/detail/', YourNameDetailView.as_view(), name='some_name_detail'),
]
```

in yourapp/templates/ you have to define 2 templates:

```
#your_name_detail.html
{% extends '_basetemplate.html' %}
{% block content %}
<div>
    <p>{{ object.name }}</p>
</div>
<p>
    <a href="{{ object.get_absolute_url }}">Update</a> |
</p>
{% endblock content %}

# your_name_edit.html
{% extends '_basetemplate.html' %}
{% block content %}
    <h5>Updating {{ object.name }}</h5>
    <form action="" method="post">
        {% csrf_token %}
        {{ form.as_p }}
        <button class="btn btn-sm btn-info ml-2" type="submit">Update</button>
    </form>
{% endblock content %}
```